# getting rel attr of link and using as text recurring

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the rel attr from a set of links in a slider, to then use as the text for the control.  I've got it working except it only lists the first rel multiple times, instead of multiple rels once.

My jQuery is

```
jQuery("#slider li a").each(function() {

    var yearValue = $(this).attr('rel');

jQuery('#controls li a').text(yearValue);
});
```

and the output html is

```
 <div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li><a rel="foo" href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="alt" /></a></li>
    <li><a rel="bar" href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="alt" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ol id="controls">
  <li id="controls1" class="first"><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="0">foo</a></li>
  <li id="controls2" class="current"><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="1">foo</a></li>
</ol>
```

I need to the ol to have **foo** and **bar**, not **foo** and **foo**

Any ideas?  Much appreciated

Comment: Don't use the `rel` attribute. Use `data-year` or some other `data-*` attribute instead. (This doesn't answer your question, hence comment instead of answer XD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
jQuery("#slider li a").each(function() {

    var index = $(this).parent().index();
    var yearValue = this.rel;

    jQuery('#controls li').eq(index).find('a').text(yearValue);

});
```

## [Nice Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/frFa9/)

Comment: thanks heaps- great! Never knew about jsfiddle either- awesome